# unresolved external symbol PriorityQueue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, binary-heap

can anyone help me with this please. I am trying to build a priority queue but keep getting a unresolved external symbol error. Any help would be well appreciated.

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node::Node(void)" (??0Node@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(void)" (??0PriorityQueue@@QAE@XZ)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to implement the Node constructor `Node::Node`.

Also a function with no parameters is written `Node()` and not `Node(void)` the latter is legacy.